# How to handle System.FormatException while running webservice webmethod?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a simple add method in my web service which takes two integer parameters, and returns Double value after addition of the two parameters.

If I insert string value instead of integer while invoking the WebMethod it gives me an exception `System.FormatException`.

Comment: Why would adding two integers result in a double?

Comment: When you pass string and try to convert in string it will give you exception.

Comment: Yes, Mairaj it is giving System.FormatException and I just have single Query how to handle that exception or how to prevent the user from inserting string value instead of integer value in the integer parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An error/exception is the correct response if the preconditions of your function have been violated. Your method requires two integers so I would expect calling it with strings instead to throw an exception telling the developer that they are using it incorrectly.

Comment: Is there any way to handle this exception while invoking the method, I mean how to restrict the user to pass the different datatype parameter.

Comment: Well, the request coming in to the webservice is just text so when you tell ASP.NET that you want an int parameter, it handles the casting/conversion from string to int for you. If you want to handle that conversion yourself, you can change the params to accept strings. You are already restricting the user to only passing ints by making the parameters of type int.